# Clarification of some concepts with regards to unit root and auto-correlation

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, residuals, unit-root

I am new to time series and would like confirmation to see if I am in the right direction w.r.t the below concepts.

1. Auto-correlation tests of a time series does not necessary assess the stationarity of a time series. But for a stationary time series, ACF should converge towards 0.
2. Serial correlation in the errors of a regression model picks up the composite effect of everything not accounted for by the explanatory variables, e.g. misspecfication, etc. Hence, even if the errors have no auto-correlation, i.e. iid, it does not mean that the endogenous variable is stationary. If that is the case, does that mean I have to perform tests for stationarity again e.g. ADF, on the endogenous variable to access stationarity?
3. To test stationarity of a time series, one can use ADF. However, this is only for the presence of unit roots in the time series, and does not test for other forms of non-stationarity, e.g. trend stationarity. Hence even if a time series does not have a unit root, i.e. rejection of H0 of ADF - indicating stationarity, it may still have a trend, thereby non-stationary. In this case, do I need to perform KPSS on top of ADF for all time series I am trying to model? From what I have seen online, most only perform either KPSS or ADF.
   Do correct me if I am wrong, but one can perform the likelihood ratio test (H0: pi=gamma=0) to assess trends in a time series. Hence, for a given time series, ADF to test for unit root and thereafter, LR test for trend-stationarity.

Comment: A couple of issues that may help you to clarify your question: 1. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "*Auto-correlation tests of a time series does not necessary access the stationarity*". 2. Residuals are not iid, even when you don't have autocorrelation.

Comment: *Access* is probably intended to mean *assess*?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thanks for you reply. Would like to clarify why residuals are not iid, even if no serial correlation, I believe that one of the assumptions made is that the residuals are white noise.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for pointing out my mistake, have edited my question! :)

Comment: OGARCH -- no, assumptions apply to errors, not residuals. Consider, for example, that while the vector of errors in a regression model have variance $\sigma^2I$ (by assumption), the residuals have variance $\sigma^2(I-H)$ (making them both heterskedastic and dependent). More generally, errors are not iid, though the exact form depends on the specific model.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, in your last sentence, is it *errors* or *residuals* that are not iid?

Comment: Yes; that should say "residuals" where it has "errors" in that last sentence (I managed to slip the reverse mistake in there). Thanks Richard.