# Is Unit Root and Stationarity the same thing?

Tags: stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

Is Unit Root and Stationarity the same thing or are they different? Assuming they are assessed through the Augmented Dickey Fuller and the Phillips Perron tests.

Comment: Check out the tag descriptions to see they are not the same thing. Also, how is your title related to the body?

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450468/dickey-fuller-test-significant-series-stationary